# Exception handling in java using finally

Tags: java, exception

```
public class CheckProg {
    public int math(int i) {
        try {
            int result = i / 0;
       // throw new IOException("in here");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 10;
        } finally {
            return 11;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CheckProg c1 = new CheckProg();
        int res = c1.math(10);
        System.out.println("Output :" + res);
   }
```

Question: If I run the above code, I get the result as  Output: 11

Why? Shouldn't the exception be caught before in the catch block and returned?

Answer (score 7):

> Shouldn't the exception be caught before in the catch block and returned ?

It *is* being caught, and that return statement *is* being executed... but then the return value is being effectively replaced by the return statement in the `finally` block, which will execute whether or not there was an exception.

See [JLS 14.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2) for details of all the possibilities. In your case, this is the path:

> If execution of the try block completes abruptly because of a throw of a value V, then there is a choice:
>
> - If the run-time type of V is assignment compatible with a catchable exception class of any catch clause of the try statement, then the first (leftmost) such catch clause is selected. The value V is assigned to the parameter of the selected catch clause, and the Block of that catch clause is executed. Then there is a choice:
>
>   - If the catch block completes normally *[ ... ignored, because it doesn't ]*
>   - If the catch block completes abruptly for reason R, then the finally block is executed. Then there is a choice:
>
>     - If the finally block completes normally *[ ... ignored, because it doesn't ]*
>     - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (and reason R is discarded).

So that bottom line is the important one - the "reason S" (in our case, returning the value 11) ends up being the way that the `try` statement completes abruptly.

Comment: @kaustubhsinha: Because a `finally` block *always* executes - that's the point of it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But the finally block is always executed afterwards and overrules the return value!

Answer (score 0):

Finally block gets executed whether or not an exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty much self-explanatory. Catch block is executing because there is an exception. Finally will execute as its execution is guaranteed irrespective of an exception.

Note - If you have given some other statement(s) instead of return, **both statements have been executed**. but in case of return, only last return is being executed.

```
} catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("10");
            } finally {
                System.out.println("11");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The "finally" keyword is used to create a block of code that follows a try block. A finally block of code always executes, whether or not an exception has occurred.

try
{

```
final int x=100;
System.out.println("The value of x is"+ x);
```

}

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);  
}
finally
{
    System.out.println("Finally Block executed");
}
```